# how to crawl forms data by using php

Tags: php, web-crawler

This website showing forex rates of different countries, and i want to crawl all of the stored data which can be shown by selecting different dates, Please help me how can i write curl or fpot crawler,

www.forex.pk/open_market_rates.asp

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can crawl the page with curl and then parse the content with a simple HTML parser.

here is one http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

simple as that.

Comment: Its very helfull if you give me some sample curl script that will parse the whole data of above mention site from 2006 to 20011 date,